# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @7fa35825

when running --stacktrace show

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\project\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Administr
ator\.gradle\caches\7.6.1\scripts\dkc0zwdwhkqegoxndbrmrixqd).
      > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_Build Script_' Unsupported class file major version 65
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I upgraded to Android Studio Hedgehog, but still the problem. Anyone any idea?